# Simple question about flow of electricity

Tags: dc, 5v, motherboard

I wanted to modify my power-on switch on my PC and decided to add few switches and LEDs before it powers up. Its more of an aesthetic modification but I have encounter one problem which is, shown in the diagram (red arow), **will the negative part of the `battery have an effect on my motherboard power-on switch/port?**

[image]
[image]

I mean I know the positive part wont touch the motherboard due to the LEDs but I have doubts about the negative part mixing up with the flow of electricity

`The "battery" comes from the motherboard USB port(It has power regardless of whether the PC is on, in standby mode or even off )

Comment: If you're going to directly wire the computer's own USB GND (negative) to a pin on the motherboard then you need to know exactly what that pin's function is. If it is a V+ supply pin then you will short it to ground and possibly damage the board.

Comment: `positive part wont touch the motherboard due to the LEDs` ... maybe not directly, but the current flowing through the LEDs definitely will

Comment: And if you manage to connect 5V to the chipset power button input pin, and if it does not tolerate 5V, the chipset may go up in smoke. I would not dare to push the actual power button unless all switches are closed.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an opto-isolator to keep your circuitry totally separate from the motherboard circuitry?